# Put label in the right place

Tags: label, pine-script, trading

I am writing a Script to place the different candlestick patterns, but when placing the labels they are placed near zero, instead of near the candle, how to solve this?

`if (Body_Size < Line_Size*0.03) and ((Body_Low - low) < Line_Size*0.2) and ((Body_Hig - low) < Line_Size*0.2) and (Hig_Line > Line_Size*0.7) and Long_Line`

`label.new(bar_index, high + (atr(30) * 1), "Gravestone Doji", style=label.style_label_down)`

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the `atr` distance outside the `if` statement.

```
//@version=4
study("My Script", overlay = true)

ema1 = ema(close, 13)
ema2 = ema(close, 50)

condition = crossover(ema1, ema2)

plot(ema1)
plot(ema2)

// 
dist = atr(30) //leave atr outside
if condition
    label.new(bar_index, high + dist, "Gravestone Doji", style=label.style_label_down)
    // label.new(bar_index, high * 1.02, "Gravestone Doji", style=label.style_label_down) //or use % as distance
```

Answer (score 0):

You placing your label by `y =  high + (atr(30) * 1)` in `label.new` function.

Expected use of the `label.new`.

```
label.new(bar_index, high, "Gravestone Doji", style=label.style_label_down)
```